# TP-Link Archer T9UH Version 2 disconnects, turns off and on on 5 Ghz network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-adapter

I have a T9UH Version 2 Wireless adapter, which i bought recently. Every 1-2 weeks it starts to go into a disconnection cycle on 5GHZ: disconnects, turns off, then turns back on and doing this after it entered the cycle. As far as i'm right the problem is connecting to 5GHZ only. A pc reboot sometimes helps, but sometimes not. Sometimes changing the USB port (plugging it to another USB port) helps too. But it happened none helped, then i changed to network router and that helped. While these things are happening, i have no problem with any other wireless devices, so there is no problem with my WIFI network.

Before this t9uh i had a t2uh adapter and it had the same problems on 5Ghz, that is why i suspect motherboard problem maybe?

I tried:
-different drivers
-different ports
-changing channels on wifi router
-tried a driver which was recommended here:
https://sites.google.com/site/bangaroovh/searchindex/tplinkdriver

None of these have any effect, after a while the problem is coming back. Now it was okay for 10 days, and today it started again, i changed ports now, and it is working again. But this is just a temporary solution. What can be the cause. I suspect it is something with my motherboard. If yes can sy help me how to find that out. My motherboard is:
GA-B250-HD3P-rev-10

And operating system is: Windows 10

Comment: Before you conclude a bad motherboard, I suggest trying a new wireless adapter to see if that works.

Comment: I had a t2uh before and it had the same symptoms but only on 5Ghz, how could i test if problem is with motherboard?

Comment: I do not know of any user way to test a motherboard. See if you can test the existing adapter on another computer

Comment: yeah i will see, the problem is that this malfunction is not always happening, sometimes after 7-10 days, but then it stays till i do one or some of the things i listed above:
-reinstall driver
-reboot
-change port

Comment: Here is a video, it is happening now, device manager is constantly refreshing, adapter is being turned off and on:
https://we.tl/t-6Cewxf9y2Y

Comment: I see Device Manager Flashing, but I do not see the little marks beside the adapter changing indicating disconnect..  If you are convinced the motherboard is the issue, you need to visit a shop (or just replace it)

Comment: Well, i just realized everytime when this diconnection is happening wifi adapter is turned off and device manager starts flashing.
Just really don't want to get a new motherboard if the issue is with the driver maybe or something else, i will wait some more days and try to find sy who had similar problems...

Comment: I would be inclined to try a different wireless adapter to eliminate this part.

Comment: "I had a t2uh before and it had the same symptoms but only on 5Ghz" - so both adapters fail. On 2.4Ghz (I'm currently on that) it is working fine ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a recommended driver that solved my problem. This driver solved my problem with no disconnections or errors in the last 20 days.

[Here](https://community.tp-link.com/us/home/forum/topic/209240#topic-reply-445256) is the answer from a TP-link guy to the same problem and [here](https://static.tp-link.com/2019/201911/20191129/T9UH.zip) is the driver which I recommend and solved my problem.